# RX 590 IN Blender and Cycles Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I don't know why, but I cant render anything in CUDA and OptiX but OpenCL work fine. I cant use Cycles render because it's very laggy.

I have newest  version of Blender and an RX 590 Red Dragon 8gb.

Why does that happen?

[image]

How can I turn on my gpu?

[image: CUDA]

Answer (score 5):

AMD Radeon cards do not have CUDA cores or OptiX, those exist only in some Nvidia Cards. Blender cannot enable what doesn't exist in your computer.

Your hardware is based on a different technology by different company.

Your only option to render ion cycles using GPU is OpenCL.